# How to find the href element value in "<a>" tag with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize, hpricot

My goal is to find the first result in google search resultes and collect the site link, so I built this script:

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'
query = gets.chomp
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.co.il/")
search_form = page.form_with(:name => "f")
search_form.field_with(:name => "q").value = query.to_s
search_results = agent.submit(search_form)
search_results = search_results.body
doc = Hpricot(search_results)
site = doc.search("a")[16,1]
url = site.to_s
puts url
```

I get a string like this:

```
url = <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallon" dir="ltr" class="l"><em>Gallon</em> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
```

But I need only the link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallon) not all the html code... 
How can I do it? I am using the gems:

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the [value of attributes](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) like this

```
(doc/"a")[16].attributes['href']
```

but I have to say that the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) 16 seems brittle.

You are also not supposed to scrape the search results, you should consider using the [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

Answer (score 6):

Since mechanize includes nokogiri you <del>can</del> should skip hpricot altogether. It will slow your code down unnecessarily. You are effectively doing the same thing twice.

```
require 'mechanize'
query = gets.chomp
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.co.il/")
search_form = page.form_with(:name => "f")
search_form.field_with(:name => "q").value = query.to_s
search_results = agent.submit(search_form)

puts search_results.links[16].href
```

Comment: untitled2.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `links' for #<String:0x00000101bc1270> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Sorry copy pasted a bit too much. Shouldn't have put the body line. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting to a string with `url = site.to_s` do `url = site[0].attributes['href']`

Comment: untitled2.rb:13:in `<main>': undefined method `attributes' for #<Hpricot::Elements:0x00000101cde518> (NoMethodError)
not working.. but thanks for trying..

Comment: Looking back at your code, `site` is an array of elements rather than a single element so you need `site[0].attributes['href']` to get the URL for the first matching `a` tag. The same principle is why Jakub's answer is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
site = doc.search("a[@href]")[16,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Waitir](http://watir.com/) is a reasonable choice to check the layout of a web page.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

#Launching browser windows and navigating to google
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("http://www.google.co.il/")

#Logging to console if a link with href = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallon present
puts browser.link(:href, "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallon").exists?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is always going to follow the same format, you could just do:

```
url.split("href=\"").last.split("\"").first
```

Comment: Honestly this is the worst possible way of doing it performance wise. You are parsing the html 3 times completely unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah it is a quick and dirty fix to his issue :)

Comment: This will run into all sorts of problems if for some reason you use a ' instead of a " or change the format of the link. It's just ugly. Although it works (hence no downvote!

Comment: The output is from Google, it will be the same till they change their choice of quote in the HREF tag, in which case a lot more can change besides this little snippet, considering they've probably changed some other stuff too. I don't see a reason for google to suddenly decide to convert its double quote to a single quote.